# Read from two data in Spring Batch

Tags: spring-batch

I want reading from two in memory base with Java config. I have two possibilities in mind.

1. read one by one with `ItemRead`, but in this case and with a large number of items it is much slower and the process becomes hard to implement (compare two base)
2. parallel reading (`itemRead` for such one/multipleReader) in the same job, but I don’t know if it is possible and how.

What would you suggest for this?

Comment: Welcome to SO, Please add more details and be specific, also read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask